# User Defined Functions - Northwind Database - Employee_Name function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I am working on an assignment and found some trouble. Here is the assignment:

This assignment will use the northwind database and the Employees table.

This will be a table user defined function.

1. Create a user defined function named Employee_Name. Pass an Employee Id as a parameter.
2. Return the First Name, Last Name, and Phone Number of the employee whose ID matches the id passed to the user defined function.
3. Create a query that uses the function and returns information for the employee with an id of 5.

Here is my solution so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Employee_Name(@employId int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN(
    SELECT FirstName,LastName,HomePhone 
    FROM dbo.Employees 
    WHERE EmployeeID = @employId
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
)

SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee_Name(5);
GO
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Employee_Name, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

Comment: Just a guess, but you might have to create a temp table in your function, populate it, then return it.

Comment: Northwind is a sample for Microsoft SQL Server. Is the MySQL tag appropriate on this question?

Comment: @DanBracuk I thought you cannot use a temp table inside of UDF?

Answer (score 1):

You have to seperate creating the function and using it. Run the `CREATE` statement before you start working on #3.
Technically, you can also just insert a `GO` before the final `SELECT` in your sample code and it should work alright.

Answer (score 1):

You function is not created because the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT FirstName,LastName,HomePhone 
FROM dbo.Employees 
WHERE EmployeeID = @employId
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

is incorrect (it inludes 3 fields in the SELECT and one, completely different in GROUP BY).

In fact you don't even need a GROUP BY, since EmployeeID is a unique value. Just create your function as

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Employee_Name(@employId int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN(
    SELECT FirstName,LastName,HomePhone 
    FROM dbo.Employees 
    WHERE EmployeeID = @employId
)
```

then your `SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee_Name(5)` will work.

And yes as @KekuSemau pointed out, either run `CREATE FUNCTION` and your `SELECT * ...` as separate queries or insert GO between them - CREATE has to be in a separate batch.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't even see that `GROUP BY` at all!

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Employees_Name(@employeeID int)
Returns Table
AS
Return(
   SELECT FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber
   FROM dbo.Employees
   WHERE EmployeeID = @employID
   )

   GO
   SELECT * FROM dbo.Employees_Name(5)
```